# A word, when you make anybody fall down with your foot

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I have a sentence to consider:

> 1. I made him fall down with one of my feet.

The sentence quoted above can be made precise if there is a specific verb that denotes making anybody fall down, as in:

> I _____ him.

See that the verb [meddle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meddle) denotes interfering with someone's affairs. Similarly, there might be verb denoting **making anyone fall down on a floor, etc. by putting your foot before theirs** See the picture below:

> [image: Picture of someone falling]

Comment: Do you mean tripped?

Comment: I believe the correct answer is, I tripped him with my foot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> *I **tripped** him [up] [with my [outstretched] foot].*

From [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trip) definition

> **trip**
>   ...
>    1.1 with object - **Cause to stumble and fall**.
>    *‘she shot out her foot to trip him up’*

You could of course trip someone [up] by throwing a banana skin<sup>1</sup> down in front of them, for example. But most often if unspecified, we assume *using my foot*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Arguably not the best example, even though it's perfectly "credible". This use of transitive ***trip*** usually implies doing something that ***blocks*** or ***entangles*** one or both of the victim's feet/legs, rather than [*lose their footing*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/footing) on an unexpectedly slippery surface.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it tripping when someone slips on a banana peel. Tripping involves your foot/ankle running into something. You could trip over a box or curb though, if you still want an example with an inanimate object.

Comment: @Kat: I did explain all that in my footnote (not to mention I qualified my use of "credible" by using scare quotes). But there are dozens of written instances of [*trip on a banana skin*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22trip+on+a+banana+skin%22), so you can hardly claim the usage can't be "stretched" that far.

Comment: If you know it's a poor example, why not swap it out for a better one? That's why I made the suggestion

Comment: @Kat: <sigh> I already *did* provide "a better example" when citing the dictionary definition. The whole point of my "banana" example (which as I pointed out, is supported by dozens of written instances in Google Books) was to show how far the usage extends beyond the core implication of *blocking / entangling* someone's foot/leg. We're obviously dealing with a non-native speaker OP here, and *that* level of detail (which should be well-known to all the natives) wouldn't normally be given by dictionaries.

Comment: A dictionary is not an example.  It's a definition.

Comment: @phoog I don’t know which ‘dictionaries’ you’ve been consulting, but a dictionary isn’t just about the ‘definition’: “*a book or electronic resource that lists the words of a language (typically in alphabetical order) and gives their meaning, or gives the equivalent words in a different language, often also providing information about pronunciation, origin, and > **usage** <.”* I would like to emphasise ‘usage’, with it being correlated to ‘example’; ‘exemplify’; ‘contexualised’ - these are all to do with **how they’re used.**

Answer (score 10):

The word you're looking for is *trip*. It can be transitive (as in your case) or intransitive.

> **trip** *verb*
>
> 1 *no object* Catch one's foot on something and stumble or fall.
>
> - ‘he tripped over his cat’
> - ‘she tripped up during the penultimate lap’
>
> 1.1 *with object* Cause to stumble and fall.
>
> - ‘she shot out her foot to trip him up’
>
> [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trip)

Your sentence would be "I tripped him," although it's usually used with *up*, as the example shows.

Comment: Might be worth noting that *trip up* can be used in a more figurative sense, meaning to commit or cause to commit an error, while *trip* is usually reserved for the physical act of falling over something. A runner who *trips* in the final lap has physically fallen, but that's not necessarily the case for a runner who *trips up* - she may have lost pace, or got distracted, or gone off the track. Likewise, a red herring in a mystery novel might trip you up, but it won't trip you.

Comment: True: that's the intransitive use and *up* can illustrate whether it should be interpreted metaphorically or not. Transitively, *up* is usually used.

Comment: @NuclearWang although, you might say one _tripped_ over a difficult word in speech, which is figurative as well.